# Using multiple Lambda versions with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have two versions of an AWS Lambda function. I wanted to attach it to two stages of API Gateway, dev and prod.

I created two aliases, `dev` and `prod`, for the two versions of the Lambda function. I created a stage variable called `fname` and provided the values dev and prod against them in the appropriate stages.

Against the Lambda function to be called in the Resources section, I provided the function name as `stageTester:${stageVariables.fname}` where stageTester is the name of my function.

It prompted me to attach permissions using AWS CLI. I ran the following command:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:xxxxxxx:function:stageTester:dev --source-arn 'arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:zzzzzz:aaaaaa/*/GET/stageTester' --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --statement-id cxbxcx9bx5-68df-4x9d-96xd-9exb497xa934 --action lambda:InvokeFunction --profile lambdaUser --region ap-south-1
```

...and a similar one for prod. I expected that this would attach the permissions appropriately.

I completed the deployment and tried to invoke the API. However, I encountered Internal Server Error every time. In the Lambda function screen, against the trigger, I see the following error

> The API with ID aaaaaa does not include a resource with path /stageTester
>   having an integration
>   arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:xxxxxxx:function:stageTester:dev on the GET
>   method

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Your setup seems to be correct. Are you sure you deployed your API to both stages; `dev` and `prod`?

Comment: Yes, I have deployed it each time. If I hardcode dev and prod instead of using the stage variable, it is working. It is only failing when I use the stage variable